# Не могу настроить Sphinx под MySql

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Устанавливал и настраивал по этой инструкции
https://vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Foxozle.com%2F2014%2F02%2F05%2Frukovodstvo-ustanovka-i-nastrojki-sphinx-na-windows-ms-sql%2F&el=snippet

[image: Ошибка выполнения команды]

В итоге на 5 шаге появилась ошибка: ERROR 2000 : Unknown MySQL error
Когда я пытаюсь подключиться к MySQL через порт 9306

Версия Sphinx 2.1.5 
Версия MySQL 8.0
Может все дело в том что MySQL "новее" и по этому не работает?

Когда я ставлю Sphinx 2.3.2-beta (последняя версия), там даже служба не запускается(ругается на конфиг)

Answer (score 0):

sphinx 2.3.2 не поддерживает клиента mysql 8. Попробуйте sphinx 3.1.1 или manticore search (форк сфинкса - https://manticoresearch.com/downloads/)